# scroll background image while scrolling information

Tags: android, image, animation, scroll

Hi i have no idea how to perform that kind of effect..
[hi an example of what i want](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QoaLSL-WW04)

The efect is, having a background image or another similar layout, scroll another layout and show the background moving.

Can someone give me a link with some information or documentation?
Thank you in advance

Comment: It is ObservableScrollView, Check out this : https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Comment: Thank you very much, thats what i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library. You also have a sample app with code, go through it. https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll

Comment: Thank you, thats what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

It's look like : ObservableScrollView

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView